# Split a word into an array of unique letters

Tags: c#, arrays, string

How do I split a string into an array of unique characters using C#?

I know that the code below splits the string into an array, but it won't pick out the unique characters:

```
string s = "robot";
char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
{
 Console.WriteLine(charArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: By "unique characters", do you mean "characters that only appear once in the string"?

Answer (score 5):

This is done easy with linq:

```
char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray().Distinct().ToArray()
```

Comment: You can just do this instead: `char[] charArray = s.Distinct().ToArray()`

Comment: @AzNjoE Just lazy, copied and pasted ;-)

Answer (score 0):

char[] charArrayNoDupes = charArray.Distinct().ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

May not be a best solution but try sorting the array and then print

```
string s = "robot";
char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
Array.Sort(charArray);
char c = '9';
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
{
    if(c != charArray[i])
    Console.WriteLine(charArray[i]);

    c = charArray[i];
}
```